# Prove that $X_t = 1/c B_{c^2 t}$ with $c \gt 0$ is a Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, independence

Let $\{ B_t \}$ a standard Brownian Motion, prove that the next process are Brownian Motions:

a) $\{ X_t \}$  where $X_t = -B_t$

b) $\{ X_t \}$  where $X_t = 1/c B_{c^2 t}$ with $c \gt 0$

c) $\{ X_t \}$ where $X_t = B_{t+t_0} -B_{t_0}$ with $t_0 \ge 0$

I know that a process  $\{ X_t \}$ is a Brownian Motion if 
1)  $X_0 =0$  2) $\{ X_t \}$ has independent and stationary increments
3) $X_t \sim N(0, {\sigma}^2 t)$

1) is easy to prove but my problem is trying to prove 2)

Any ideas?

Comment: You have trouble with all three, a), b), c)?  What are the increments of $-B_t$ ?  Are they independent?  Are they stationary?

Comment: 2) is easy in all three cases. Did you make an attempt to write down the increments?